# Forward apache log as syslog messages

Tags: apache

I have an apache installation on linux server. I want to forward error log entries as syslog to a remote syslog server. This is the configuration I made:

On the Linux server:

[file httpd.conf], line added:

LogLevel crit

ErrorLog syslog

[file syslog.conf] line added:

local7.crit   /var/log/apache.crit

[root@localhost root]# killall -HUP syslogd

[root@localhost root]# /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl restart

[file syslog.conf] line added

local7.crit @192.168.1.1

I don't see any syslog messages on 192.168.1.1 . The upd port 514 is open. What's wrong?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem and I found this helpful

http://blog.papertrailapp.com/post/12137863501/send-apache-access-logs-to-remote-syslog-in-1-line

"This combines netcat, Apache’s CustomLog configuration directive, and Apache’s piped logs feature"

Hope this help